# Picasa: Seach by tags with multiple AND or OR

Tags: search, tags, picasa

I have lots of pictures in Picasa and have spent quite some time tagging all of them. Now I'm desperately trying to find a way to be able to create quick overviews that match certain criteria (my tags, basically). If I type 'Billy' (or 'tag:Billy') in the Search bar it will nicely display all pictures with Billy in it. Same thing with searching for 'Joe', no problems finding all pictures with Joe in it.

However, what if I only want to see the pictures that have *BOTH* Billy and Joe in it (in the same picture, with two tags)? Or to take it a step further, is there a way to display all pictures of both Billy AND Joe (so together in the same picture), but *NOT* with e.g. Julia ...? All this assuming that all pictures are accurately tagged of course ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Picasa.

You need to consider migrating to a more serious photo management tool that can build more complex queiries, like find me all JPEG photos with John and Julia but not with Mark, taken in 2012.

Plus as you can see in the below screenshot you can create and search hierarchical tags (the feature that is missed in Picasa)

[image]